# Listen to scroll event from overflow:hidden elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to synchronize the scrolling between two separate panels / divs.

One element has `overflow: auto` while the other has `overflow: hidden` (sort of trying to replicate a grid with frozen columns).

I can sync the scroll when the event happens within the element with `overflow: auto` but not the one with `overflow: hidden` (which is sort of normal if you ask me).

However, is there a workaround for this? I want to synchronize the scrolling both ways.

Here's a fiddle that will illustrate my issue (try scrolling in both panels): http://jsfiddle.net/0zzbkyqg/

Also, this thing seems to happen here already: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/frozen-columns but I just can't understand how they're doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should make use of the [`wheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel) event which is triggered when you roll the mouse wheel, regardless of whether the section of the view has scrolled or not.
[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/3c65vnL8/1/)

```
$("#panel-left > table").on('wheel', function (e) { 
     // your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you don't need jQuery to do that.

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/ty0jyr4y/

I've removed the `position: absolute` and `overflow` properties from the panels and added `float: left` to make them inline (could also use `display: inline-block`), and added `height: 400px`, `width: 417px` and `overflow: auto` to the container.

The container's width is set to `417px` instead of `400px` because the scroll bar takes 17 pixels of space (across all browsers according to [here](http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/browser-scrollbar-width.php)).

Works beautifully. Is this what you want?